# android lifecycle methods don't call

Tags: android, lifecycle

Can anyone help me ? In my android application, in activity class. I overriden onStart() and onStop() methods. But when I just fast minimize and restore application, this methods don't call. Why ? and how I can force detect and call it's ?

Comment: Because they aren't called in a right way. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStart() AND http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop()

Comment: onResume() will be called when you wakeup the app from background.

Comment: there is no such thing like "fast minimize"... what actually did you do?

Comment: tap to minimize app button and fast tap after again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When You minimize or restore application according to life cycle it will call onResume method
so track your application when it start it will call onCreate and onStart then it will call OnResume Method.

Answer (score 1):

onResume() will be called when you wake up the app from background.

Refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html to know more about the life cycle of an activity.